# EFT matching: using tree-level to perform 1-loop-level

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, renormalization, dimensional-analysis, effective-field-theory

I'm reading the [Saclay Lectures on EFT](https://userswww.pd.infn.it/%7Eferuglio/Falkowski.pdf), and I don't understand how it uses the tree-level matching to compute the 1-loop-level matching. To simplify, in this post I'll put its $C_6,\lambda_1=0$ since they're relevant to the full matching but not to my question.
I have these Lagrangians:

$$\mathcal{L}_\text{UV}=\frac{1}{2}[(\partial\phi)^2-m_L^2\phi^2+(\partial H)^2-M^2 H^2]-\frac{\lambda_0}{4!}\phi^4-\frac{\lambda_2}{6!}\phi^2 H^2\tag{2.1}$$
$$\mathcal{L}_\text{EFT}=\frac{1}{2}[(\partial\phi)^2-m^2\phi^2]-\frac{C_4}{4!}\phi^4.\tag{2.2}$$
The tree-level matching is trivial, and states
$$m^2=m_L^2, \quad C_4=\lambda_0.\tag{2.10+13}$$
Now onto 1-loop-level matching, focusing on the 2-point function and evaluating it at its pole both in the EFT theory and the UV theory, obtaining two formulas:
$$\text{EFT}\rightarrow m_\text{phys}^2=m^2-\frac{C_4 m^2}{32\pi^2}\left[\log\left(\frac{\mu^2}{m^2}\right)+1\right]\tag{2.19}$$
$$\text{UV}\rightarrow m_\text{phys}^2=m_L^2-\frac{\lambda_0 m_L^2}{32\pi^2}\left[\log\left(\frac{\mu^2}{m_L^2}\right)+1\right]-\frac{\lambda_2 M^2}{32\pi^2}\left[\log\left(\frac{\mu^2}{M^2}\right)+1\right].\tag{2.28}$$
The next step is obviously to equate (*match*) the two quantities at the same scale $\mu$. The book finds
$$m^2(\mu)=m_L^2(\mu)-\frac{\lambda_2 M^2}{32\pi^2}\left[\log\left(\frac{\mu^2}{M^2}\right)+1\right]\tag{2.29}$$
where, I presume, the part with $\log(\mu^2/m^2)$ is absent because the tree-level matching results were used. But if they were used to cancel those terms, why can't they also be used to cancel $m$ and $m_L$ in the above equation?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the answer lies in the fact that, in equation $(2.29)$, one has the *scaling masses*, dependent on $\mu$. Therefore the terms in $\log(\mu^2/m^2)$ aren't canceled, but are included in the definition of $m^2(\mu)$. This is done because the light masses $m$ and $m_L$ have the same IR scaling, but are modified in the UV by the presence of $M$, which is left out of the scaling.